# Paypal REST API Process

Tags: paypal

Please correct me if I am wrong regarding my understanding about Paypal Rest Api process.

In reference to the links below:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/create-billing-plan/

https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-node-SDK/blob/master/samples/subscription/billing_plans/create.js

I came up to a conclusion that in order for the paypal api to work, the merchant must create:

1. A custom button
2. The button must create a request to paypal in other words the merchant must manually fill out the JSON object stated on:

https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-node-SDK/blob/master/samples/subscription/billing_plans/create.js

with the merchant's product info.

3. Pass the request to paypal
4. Store the paypal response to your database.

Please advise, there are too few information out there. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, my question above is confirmed except that you need to active the created billing plan.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/create-billing-plan/#activate-the-billing-plan